# How do I populate datagridview with dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wpf, visual-studio

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var select = "SELECT * FROM Products";

    var c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-4D1RO14\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"); // Your Connection String here

    var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);

    var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

I need to show the product in a datagridview, then when I click a row, it shows the supplier name. I think in order to do that, I need to have a relationship for the products and suppliers table right?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily; you could just retrieve the current row from the grid whenever the event fires to indicate the current row has changed, and then retrieve the supplier id from the underlying row. However, my preference for situations like this is to use a BindingSource, and hook to the [CurrentChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.currentchanged?view=netframework-4.8) event.

You'll do yourself a large favor if you add a strongly typed dataset to your project, connect it to your database and use the tableadapters and typed datatables. After you've done this step (add a new dataset to the project, open it, right click the surface and choose new tableadapter, fill in the connection details and `select * from supplers`, repeat for products) you can open the Data Sources window, drag the Suppliers and Products nodes onto the form and you'll get a datagridview for each, bound through a bindingsource to a single instance of a dataset that has both tables. You can then code this event handler on the ProductBindingSource:

```
private void ProductBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ProductBindingSource.Current == null) return;

    var pr = (ProductBindingSource.Current as DataRowView).Row as MyDataSetName.ProductsRow;

    var ta = new SuppliersTableAdapter(); //you might even have a suppliersTableAdapter on the form; no need to make a new one if this is the case

    ta.Fill(dataset1.Suppliers, pr.SupplierID);

}
```

Comment: there should be only 1 datagridview and the supplier name should be shown in a message box

Comment: ok, so just add another line of code under what I put, saying `MessageBox.Show(dataset1.Suppliers[0].Name)` or similar. Get the strongly typed dataset/tableadapters working first before taking this step

Comment: how do I put in the suppliers table adapter? (nvm)

Comment: public SuppliersRow this[int index] {
                get {
                    return ((SuppliersRow)(this.Rows[index]));
                }
            }
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'There is no row at position 0.'

Comment: You need to fill the table first, or check whether the row count > 0

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you need to add foreign key between two tables.

You can try the following code to show supplier name from current datagridview.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var select = "SELECT * FROM Product";

            var c = new SqlConnection(@""); // Your Connection String here

            var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);

            var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int value =Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@""); // Your Connection String here
            connection.Open();
            string sql = string.Format("select SupplierName from Supplier inner join Product On Supplier.NewId = {0}", value);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = reader["SupplierName"].ToString();
            }

        }
```

Result:
[image]